# Function name macros which work accross compilers

Tags: c-preprocessor

There are preprocessor macros which define the name of a function inside it, `__func__` for g++ and `__FUNCTION__` for cl. (**func** is the c++ standard way of doing this (from dcl.fct.def.general) but it is not implmented everywhere)

For source which will be compiled by both of these compilers what should I do?

I have tried

```
#ifdef __func__
#define FUNCTION_NAME __func__
#else
#ifdef __FUNCTION__
#define FUNCTION_NAME __FUNCTION__
#else
#error "Function name macro not found"
#endif
#endif
```

but as it is not in a function the macros are not defined.

I have also tried

```
void implementation_detail() {
#ifdef __func__
#define FUNCTION_NAME __func__
#else
#ifdef __FUNCTION__
#define FUNCTION_NAME __FUNCTION__
#else
#error "Function name macro not found"
#endif
#endif
}
```

but that also gives an error.

How can I do this so it will work in multiple compliers?

Comment: `#elseifdef` is not a standard preprocessor directive.  If you're looking for something cross-compiler, don't use a compiler-specific extension here.  You'll either have to do a nested `#else`-`#ifdef`, or factor things differently.

Comment: The `__func__` macro is defined in the C++ standard and as such it is a real shame that it doesn't seem to work with all compilers.

Comment: @Agentlien I had a look in my copy, but I made the mistake of looking under 16 Preprocessing directives. I'll update with this info.

Comment: @JoeZ Thanks, I didn't realise that was non-standard I'll change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that there is a boost macro for this, BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION.

From looking at the source code [here](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/current_function.hpp) how this is implemented is they use an inline function like so.

```
inline void current_function_helper()
{

#if defined(__GNUC__) || (defined(__MWERKS__) && (__MWERKS__ >= 0x3000)) || (defined(__ICC) && (__ICC >= 600)) || defined(__ghs__) || defined(__DMC__)`
...
```

(also it is declared in a namespace called detail which is very wise)

I will use this.

EDIT: implementing __func__ will be in the Visual Studio customer technology preview out now, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-the-visual-c-compiler-november-2013-ctp.aspx).